# Getting TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0') after running the code below. Testing react app. How can I resolve it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Card.js

file using props

```js
import React from 'react';

const Card = (props) => {

    return (
            <div  className="bg-light-yellow dib br3 pa3 ma1 grow bw2 shadow-5">
            <img alt='robots' src="https://robohash.org/alpha?200x200" />
                <div>
                    <h1>{props.name}</h1>
                    <p>{props.email}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            );
}

export default  Card;
```

robots.js file having array

```js
export const robots = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Leanne Graham',
    username: 'Bret',
    email: 'Sincere@april.biz'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Ervin Howell',
    username: 'Antonette',
    email: 'Shanna@melissa.tv'
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'Clementine Bauch',
    username: 'Samantha',
    email: 'Nathan@yesenia.net'
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    name: 'Patricia Lebsack',
    username: 'Karianne',
    email: 'Julianne.OConner@kory.org'
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    name: 'Chelsey Dietrich',
    username: 'Kamren',
    email: 'Lucio_Hettinger@annie.ca'
  },
  {
    id: 6,
    name: 'Mrs. Dennis Schulist',
    username: 'Leopoldo_Corkery',
    email: 'Karley_Dach@jasper.info'
  },
  {
    id: 7,
    name: 'Kurtis Weissnat',
    username: 'Elwyn.Skiles',
    email: 'Telly.Hoeger@billy.biz'
  },
  {
    id: 8,
    name: 'Nicholas Runolfsdottir V',
    username: 'Maxime_Nienow',
    email: 'Sherwood@rosamond.me'
  },
  {
    id: 9,
    name: 'Glenna Reichert',
    username: 'Delphine',
    email: 'Chaim_McDermott@dana.io'
  },
  {
    id: 10,
    name: 'Clementina DuBuque',
    username: 'Moriah.Stanton',
    email: 'Rey.Padberg@karina.biz'
  }
];
```

Browser is pointing out error in this file inside render function at first card component.
I'm new to react and stucked at this error.

index.js

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import Card from './Card';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import 'tachyons';
import {robots}  from './robots';


ReactDOM.render(
  <div>
 <Card id={robots[0].id} name={robots[0].name} email={robots[0].email}/>
    <Card id={robots[1].id} name={robots[1].name} email={robots[1].email}/>
  <Card id={robots[2].id} name={robots[2].name} email={robots[2].email}/>
  </div>
  ,
  document.getElementById('root')
  );


reportWebVitals();
```

This is the error

```js
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')
Module../src/index.js
C:/Users/Rahul/Desktop/robofriends/src/index.js:12
   9 | 
  10 | ReactDOM.render(
  11 |   <div>
> 12 |  <Card id={robots[0].id} name={robots[0].name} email={robots[0].email}/>
  13 |   <Card id={robots[1].id} name={robots[1].name} email={robots[1].email}/>
  14 |   <Card id={robots[2].id} name={robots[2].name} email={robots[2].email}/>
  15 |   </div>
```

Using these 3 files to create the react app, **webpack_require** error is just after the error mentioned above.help out

Comment: It looks like that your import is not working and therefore `robots` is undefined. Can you posted the bundled JS created by Webpack?

Comment: Well the way I was exporting robots.js `export const robots` was not right I think, I removed export before const at start and added `export {robots};` at the end in robots.js file and it worked. That's why import was not working. Thanks for the input @Krisztian.